# Active Connections Current Count in Weblogic not getting decremented ever after closing session

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, weblogic11g

I am opening and closing a session using Hibernate but even after session.close,the connections to the datasource are still not getting released.

1.I am not using flush or clear.Only session.close is used.
2.When Inactive Connection Timeout is set to some value other than zero ,then connections are getting release but a new error comes up.Please find below that error.

The code that i am using is mentioned below:

@Component
public class UserLoginDetailsDao {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}


public boolean insertUserDetails(String hexGuid,String callCenter,String firstname,String lastname,String email,String userId)  {

    boolean usercheck=false;
    Session session=null;
    Transaction tnx =null;
    try
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        tnx=session.beginTransaction(); 

        UserInfo user=(UserInfo)session.get(UserInfo.class,hexGuid);

        if(user ==null){


            user=new UserInfo();

            user.setFirstname(firstname);
            user.setLastname(lastname);
            user.setHexGuid(hexGuid);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setUserId(userId);
            session.save(user);
            tnx.commit();
            usercheck=true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally{
        if(tnx!=null)
            tnx=null;

        if(session!=null)
        {

            session.close();

        }
        System.out.println("session check disconnectivity" + session.isConnected());
    }
    return usercheck;
}
```

}

Please help on this.I tried a lot.
Thanks!